# I want to create a trigger, where in data insertion trigger updates a quantity of non-primary or primary in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to create a trigger, where in data insertion for the same userid, trigger updates a quantity by 1, of particular row in another table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_after_insert
AFTER INSERT
   ON visitor
   FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (old.visresid = new.visresid)

BEGIN
   UPDATE visqty
   SET primaryvisqty = primaryvisqty + 1
   WHERE old.visresid = new.visresid
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Table updated');
END;
```

Comment: Insert doesn't have an "old" (all null) - you're adding new lines, not replacing existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_after_insert
   AFTER INSERT ON visitor
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   UPDATE visqty
   SET primaryvisqty = primaryvisqty + 1
   WHERE visresid = :new.visresid;
END;
```

- remove `WHEN` clause
- fix `WHERE` clause
- terminate `UPDATE` statement with a semi-colon
- remove `DBMS_OUTPUT` call (clients, that don't support it, won't see anything anyway)

---

With sample tables:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE visitor
  2  (
  3     visresid   NUMBER
  4  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE visqty
  2  (
  3     visresid        NUMBER,
  4     primaryvisqty   NUMBER
  5  );

Table created.
```

As trigger updates the visqty table, it means that it is pre-populated with data:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO visqty (visresid, primaryvisqty)
  2       VALUES (1, 0);

1 row created.
```

Trigger:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_after_insert
  2     AFTER INSERT
  3     ON visitor
  4     FOR EACH ROW
  5  BEGIN
  6     UPDATE visqty
  7        SET primaryvisqty = primaryvisqty + 1
  8      WHERE visresid = :new.visresid;
  9  END;
 10  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO visitor (visresid)
  2       VALUES (1);

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM visqty;

  VISRESID PRIMARYVISQTY
---------- -------------
         1             1

SQL>
```

---

If `visqty` isn't pre-populated, use `merge` instead of `update`:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_after_insert
  2     AFTER INSERT
  3     ON visitor
  4     FOR EACH ROW
  5  BEGIN
  6     MERGE INTO visqty a
  7          USING (SELECT :new.visresid AS visresid FROM DUAL) b
  8             ON (a.visresid = b.visresid)
  9     WHEN MATCHED
 10     THEN
 11        UPDATE SET a.primaryvisqty = a.primaryvisqty + 1
 12     WHEN NOT MATCHED
 13     THEN
 14        INSERT     (visresid, primaryvisqty)
 15            VALUES (:new.visresid, 1);
 16  END;
 17  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It still does make an error. ORA-24344: success with compilation error. Spent 4 hours for a solution finding, and still can't find it.

Comment: Have a look at example I posted.

Comment: "switch to BEFORE (you can't use the :new pseudorecord in an AFTER trigger)" Yes, you can use `:NEW` in an `AFTER` trigger. You cannot modify the `:NEW` record in an `AFTER` trigger but the OP does not want to do that; they want to insert into a different table and just reference the new values.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c77808c72638e70e6c75369c995c0fb7

I just copied a part of my db.
I just now need to create an entry if not existing. But still did not finish y trigger

Comment: That's because of ORA-00904: A"."VISRESID": invalid identifier -- there's no VISRESID column in VISQTY table. And there's no foreign key constraint which tells (me) which columns to join. You should know it and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

`:old.visresid` will always be `NULL` on an `INSERT` so your filter `WHERE :old.visresid = :new.visresid` (correcting the missing `:` on the `:NEW` and `:OLD` bind variables) will never match anything.

If you want to add one to the row in `visqty` for each row added to `visitor` then you can use:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_after_insert
  AFTER INSERT ON visitor
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE visqty
  SET    primaryvisqty = primaryvisqty + 1;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=905c5b29da56ec04d6470be96035e131)*

---

> As I have boolean condition, and I would insert a data to particular field based on 0 or 1, how I could then achieve this? For example, if primvis = 1 then SET primaryvisqty = primaryvisqty + 1, if primvis = 0, then instead non primaryvisqty = primaryvisqty + 1?

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_after_insert
  AFTER INSERT ON visitor
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.primvis = 1 THEN
    UPDATE visqty
    SET    primaryvisqty = primaryvisqty + 1;
  ELSE
    UPDATE visqty
    SET    nonprimaryvisqty = nonprimaryvisqty + 1;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=5aebe276c3e7f8d91db909cb9b09c295)*

---

You could use a trigger:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_after_insert
  AFTER INSERT ON visitor
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  MERGE INTO visqty a
  USING DUAL b
  ON (a.permvisid = :NEW.visresid)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
    SET primaryvisqty = primaryvisqty + :new.isprimary,
        othervisqty   = othervisqty   + 1 - :new.isprimary
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (permvisid, primaryvisqty, othervisqty)
    VALUES (:new.visresid, :new.isprimary, 1 - :new.isprimary);
END;
/
```

But it seems that what you really want is a view and not a table and a trigger:

```sql
CREATE VIEW visqty(permvisid, primaryvisqty, othervisqty) AS
SELECT r.rid,
       COUNT(CASE v.isprimary WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) AS primaryvisqty,
       COUNT(CASE v.isprimary WHEN 0 THEN 1 END) AS othervisqty
FROM   residents r
       LEFT OUTER JOIN visitor v
       ON (r.rid = v.visresid)
GROUP BY r.rid
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=0f6045fa9143fae7faa969c8977f897b)*

Comment: Thanks for this. As I have boolean condition, and I would insert a data to particular field based on 0 or 1, how I could then achieve this? For example, if primvis = 1 then SET    primaryvisqty = primaryvisqty + 1, if primvis = 0, then instead non primaryvisqty = primaryvisqty + 1?

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_after_insert
      AFTER INSERT ON visitor
      FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      IF :new.isprimary = 1 THEN
         UPDATE visqty
         SET    primaryvisqty = primaryvisqty + 1;
       ELSE
       UPDATE visqty
       SET    nonprimaryvisqty = nonprimaryvisqty + 1;
     END IF;
  END;

This still makes an error ORA-24344: success with compilation error

Comment: @ArtursRadionovs Works fine for me [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=87d3bcf4370de2439378cd626f73cbed)

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c77808c72638e70e6c75369c995c0fb7
Can you please check this one?

Comment: fixed. Thanks a lot.
What's wrong with the below?

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_check_sum2
BEFORE INSERT ON visitor
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

BEGIN
 IF ((SELECT SUM(primaryvisqty + othervisqty) FROM visqty WHERE permvisid = :new.visresid)<5) THEN
 RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20124, 'VISITOR LIMIT');
 END IF;
 END;

Comment: 2 `BEGIN` and only 1 `END` and using `SELECT` inside an `IF` statement.